# Forcing domain to load over HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl, https

I've recently installed on my website a CloudFlare SSL Certificate.
However, when I am trying to force my website over HTTPS, I fail.

I firstly attempted to create a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS from my web host control panel (Hostinger), but apparently, you cannot create a redirect for the same website.

After this, I went to the **.htaccess** file and edited it, adding the following codes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Error: The broswer does not redirects me to load the domain over HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Error: In Google Chrome I get the following error screen:

**This webpage has a redirect loop**

***ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS***

In Opera, the web page does not load.

I tried to delete my Chrome's cache, but it still didn't work.

Any tips?

Comment: Same here, did you find any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise CloudFlare's page rules. Login to your account, head over to page rules. Click "Create Page Rule".

type in your domain name in the following format: `http://example.com/*` and add the setting

> Always use HTTPS

Then press save and wait 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks I tried about 5 variations of htaccess rules to fix the looping issue, this solved it for me )